# How to stop resizing of JPanel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I have reminder class extending JPanel, with boxlayout and

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500))
```

In the mainclass I have JFrame

```
rem = new Reminder();

            frame.setSize(900,900);
            rem.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(rem,BorderLayout.CENTRE);
            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();
```

And I want the reminder panel in the centre of the jframe without changing its size(500,500) and frame should not change it size(900,900). When I run the above code, rem panel is totally expanded. How to make the rem panel in centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way: use AbsoluteLayout and position the "rem" exactly where you want with a graphical editor.
Then set invariable size for frame:

```
 frame.setResizable(false);
```

Comment: For those who came here wanting to be able to resize the JFrame without resizing the panel (as question is worded), the issue lies in your LayoutManager.  I recommend looking into MigLayout as it's much easier to learn than LayoutManagers, and quite powerful.  Also, setMaximum/Preffered/Min size or @Override-ing getMax/Min/Pref size are potential things to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `BorderLayout`. Why do you use a BorderLayout if it is exactly what you don't want to have?

Edit: `BoxLayout` is one choice, if you really need to position everything absolutely yourself, you can also decide to use no layout manager, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: I frame layout with boxlayout, i am facing error as boxlayout cannot be shared.

Comment: what do you mean by "cannot be shared"?

Comment: when i setlayout as boxlayout to jframe, its giving me error as boxlayout cannot be shared? even i have no idea why I got this error.

Comment: @vijay That's because you are doing something like this: `panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS))` the first argument of the new BoxLayout should be the same as the panel you're attaching it to, panel1, in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you wanna use a Borderlayout I'm pretty sure it's a typo in your code:

```
frame.add(rem,BorderLayout.CENTRE);
```

should be:

```
frame.add(rem,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Could it be this small thing that's bothering you?